# Node Postgresql How to Prevent Transaction from Aborting

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using [pg/transaction](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions) to handle a complex process. It can be simplified as this:

```
async() => {
    const client = await new Pool().connect();
    try {
        await client.query("BEGIN");
        await client query("query 1");
        try {
            await client query("query 2");
            // Some error happen
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        await client query("query 3");
        await client query("COMMIT");
    } catch(err) {
        await client.query("ROLLBACK");
    } finally {
        client.release
    }
}
```

The problem is that when query2 returns an error, the client fails to execute query3 even I don't Rollback the process. The error it returns is `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transction block`. Is there any way to prevent the transaction from being aborted when a query error happends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour because it is the whole point of a transaction. If you don't want queries 1,2,3 to all succeed or all fail together you probably don't want them in the same transaction.

However, if what you want is really "1 and (2 or 3)" then you should put a `SAVEPOINT` after query 1 and rollback to that savepoint in the event of an error in query 2.